# Sheets- How to quickly calculate the standard deviation of a set of dice?

Tags: google-sheets

I apologize if this is formatted poorly. I am new to spread sheets and have the spelling capabilities of a kindergarten.

I am attempting to find the standard deviation of a set of different sized dice in google sheets. The dice sizes are limited to 4, 6, 8, 10, and 12 sided dice. The goal is that I can input the amount of dice I have and calculate the standard deviation

eg. For 2d4 and 1d12, the standard deviation is 3.8. Sample table:

| Die Sides | Dice Rolls |
| --- | --- |
| d12 | 1 |
| d10 | 0 |
| d8 | 0 |
| d6 | 0 |
| d4 | 2 |

Is there an method (Function or script) that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: how did you calculate `3.8` ?

Comment: I calculated 3.8 by hand. I am unsure of how to use the STDEV function to do what I want.

Comment: No, but *how* did you calculate 3.8? What method are you using?

Comment: The formula SD= √(∑(x-m)^2)/n)

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. The die amount is the input. The purpose of this is to balance a table top game I am developing and need a quick method of determining the expected range of a set of dice.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do. Your picture does not line up with what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following input format as desired in your question:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 |

Treating each dice roll as a [discrete-uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) random variable from `[a=1, b]`, we can say that the variance is given as

```
((b - a + 1)^2 - 1) / 12
```

or since `a` is always `1`:

```
(b ^ 2 - 1) / 12
```

Since these are independent events, the combined variance is the sum of variances.

Standard Deviation is the square root of Variance, so this gives us:

```
=ArrayFormula(SQRT(SUM(B:B * (A:A^2 - 1)) / 12))
```

In your example, this yields `3.796928583`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to do this for hours.